# Save Highcharts chart to file on disk

Tags: c#, highcharts, export

I am using the following C# code to produce a chart and then incorporate it in an HTML screen. I want to simultaneously save the chart, preferably in svg format to disk for later incorporation in a pdf file. The examples all seem to have this happening in javascript. How do I do it in this C# code please.

```
@using Highsoft.Web.Mvc.Charts
@using Highsoft.Web.Mvc.Charts.Rendering
@using System.Collections 



@{
    List<string> values = new List<string>();
    Model.columnSeries.ForEach(u => values.Add(u.Name.ToString()));

    var chartOptions = new Highcharts
    {
        Boost =
        {
            UseGPUTranslations = true
        },
        Title = new Title
        {
             Text = @Model.Title
        },
        Subtitle = new Subtitle
        {
              Text = @Model.SubTitle
        },
        XAxis = new List<XAxis>
        {
            new XAxis
            {
                Categories = values,
                AllowDecimals = false,
                Labels = new XAxisLabels
            {
                Rotation = -45
                //Formatter = "formatXAxis"
            }
        }
    },

        YAxis = new List<YAxis>
        {   new YAxis
            {
                Title = new YAxisTitle
                {
                    Text = @Model.YaxisLabel
                },
                Labels = new YAxisLabels
                {
                //Formatter = "formatYAxis"
                }
            }

        },
        Tooltip = new Tooltip
        {
            PointFormat = "{series.name}: <b>{point.y:.0f}</b>"
        },
        PlotOptions = new PlotOptions
        {
            Column = new PlotOptionsColumn
            {
            }
        },
        Series = new List<Series>
        {
            new ColumnSeries
            {
                Data = @Model.columnSeries
            }
        }
    };


    chartOptions.ID = "Services";
    var renderer = new HighchartsRenderer(chartOptions);
    //chart.exportChart();
}
@Html.Raw(renderer.RenderHtml())
```

and inserted into HTML (view) with

```
 @await Component.InvokeAsync("ServiceChart", new {clientId = Model.ClientId, startDate = Model.StartDate, endDate = Model.EndDate})
```

Answer (score 0):

Examples of downloading SVG from the website are here: https://dotnet.highcharts.com/Highcharts/Demo/Gallery?demo=LineBasic&theme=default

However, if you wanted to do it on the backend side, using the .NET wrapper it does not have such functionality. In this case you would use Export Server: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/render-charts-serverside

Comment: Solved by placing on canvas, and using JSON object passed to web service to store the image on the server.